# Search on bootstrap dropdown

Tags: model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

hi there im wondering how to add a search option on to this dropdown

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="employees">
            <h5>Workforce <span style="color:red">*</span></h5>
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.company.employees, ViewBag.employees as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                             "Select employees",
                             new { @class = "form-control", @id = "employees", onchange = "employees(this.value)" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.company.employees, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the dropdown as HTML?

Comment: yes i suppose i can

Comment: If you're looking to filter the options inside that drop-down and you're using JQuery I'd recommend using something like select2 https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: Are you going to add the HTML?